# How to do Feature Selection if X is nominal and y is nominal as well?

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

According to [machine learning mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/). We should use `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2` or `sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif` for X nominal and y nominal.

However, both `chi2` and `mutual_info_classif` do not accept X nominal. It wants a X numeric.

I am confused whether to encoded these X nominal with OrdinalEncoder, LabelEncoder, or OneHotEncoder. My guts tell me to use OneHotEncoder because nominal does not have any relationship between 0, 1, 2.

However, the result is gibberish and I don't understand why 1 column turns into 5 mutual_info value. So, I believe OneHotEncoder is not supposed to be used with mutual_info_classif.

What I've did:

1. Use OneHotEncoder

```
mutual_info_classif(OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_train['workclass'].values.reshape(-1,1)), y_train)
```

> array([1.57589114e-03, 5.67522742e-04, 6.98987129e-05, 6.94975390e-03,
> 8.32101543e-03, 2.74923178e-04, 3.14836186e-05, 1.51472199e-04])

2. Use OrdinalEncoder

```
mutual_info_classif(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X_train['workclass'].values.reshape(-1,1))), y_train)
```

array([0.01156094])

3. Use LabelEncoder

```
mutual_info_classif(LabelEncoder().fit_transform(X_train['workclass']).reshape(-1,1), y_train)
```

> array([0.0160716])

4. Use OneHotEncoder again and assume that `column_value` with high mi, then choose the top column as features.

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
mi = mutual_info_classif(enc.fit_transform(X_train[nominal]), y_train)
pd.DataFrame({'mi': mi}, index=enc.get_feature_names_out()) \
  .sort_values(by='mi', ascending=False)
```

> marital_status_ Married-civ-spouse    1.070108e-01
> relationship_ Husband   8.200896e-02
> marital_status_ Never-married   6.353818e-02
> relationship_ Own-child 3.674731e-02
> sex_ Male   2.601720e-02
> ... ...

Comment: Why do you want to do feature selection?

Comment: @user2974951 I want to just use features that have strong relationship with the target variable instead of all features.

Comment: Why? How many features do you have? How big is your sample? What model are you going to use afterwards?

Comment: Because I am not sure which features to use. I am still learning to understand how to determine "how to correlation between X nominal and y nominal". The samples about 300k rows. I am going to use LogisticRegression or SVM. The dataset is in BigQuery `bigquery-public-data.ml_datasets.census_adult_income`